# UIWebView and MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, ios7, uiwebview, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmoviewcontroller

I hvae addd one webview having youtube link. When user play viedo it defaults open iOS movie player. I want to track notification of that movie player when it exits full screen or playing stopped. I have tried all notification generated by MPMoviewPlayerController . None of them are being fired. It fiers only when we instatinate MPMoviewPlayerViewCotntroller object and present MPMoviewPlayer from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's becuase Youtube videos inside `UIWebView` are not `MPMoviewPlayerViewCotntroller`.

On iOS7:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerWillEnterFullscreen:)
                                             name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification"
                                           object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerWillExitFullscreen:)
                                             name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerWillExitFullscreenNotification"  object:nil];
```

On iOS8 it's a bit of a problem because these events are gone, and you need to add observer like so:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(ios8EnterFullscreen:)
                                             name:UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(ios8ExitFullscreen:)
                                             name:UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification object:nil];
```

And check that when it fires it is indeed a movie player (because it fires also on UIAlertView and stuff):

```
- (void)ios8EnterFullscreen:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ([notification.object isMemberOfClass:[UIWindow class]])
    {
         //do your thing...
    }
}
```